# Let the user adapt the width of columns on a table

Tags: javascript, django, user-interface, bootstrap-5

I am working on a web app (Django, Bootstrap). I would like to display a table and let the user adapt the width of the colums (as it's done on Sharepoint libraries display page).

Any idea of the tools and documentation explaining how to achieve that?
Notice: I am far from being an expert... let's say beginner + :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't written any code, yet! My problem is that I have no clue about how to start !